# JAX-WS and curly braces syntax

Tags: spring, jax-ws

All over the Internet I find code examples of JAX-WS beans being defined in this fashion:

```xml
<jaxws:client name="{http://cxf.apache.org/}MyService" createdFromAPI="true">
```

What is the meaning of the curly braces here exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to specify individual examples of where you've seen it, but from what you've shared here, this seems to be erroneous use of that naming convention.
See, [the schema for the Spring-CXF XML configuration document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html-single/XML_Configuration_Reference/files/http.cxf.apache.org.jax/element/client.html#attr_serviceName) supports two types of "name" attributes:

1. [`name`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html-single/XML_Configuration_Reference/files/http.cxf.apache.org.jax/element/client.html#attr_name): use this to name just the bean within the spring context - treat it no differently as you would adding `id` to a spring bean. No need for a namespace or prefixing of any kind
2. [`serviceName`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html-single/XML_Configuration_Reference/files/http.cxf.apache.org.jax/element/client.html#attr_serviceName): this name should come from the WSDL as part of the `name` attribute from the `definitions` root element. It's *this one* that uses the QName format - what you have here as `{http://cxf.apache.org/}MyService` which the CXF API will try to match with what's in the WSDL of the SOAP service you're consuming.

**TL;DR:** that naming convention with the URL prefix doesn't belong on the `name` attribute but on the `serviceName` attribute and its value ought to come from the WSDL file.